# Android SQLite permissions (to avoid a skype like situation)

Tags: android, security, sqlite

Recently it has been discovered that "sloppy" programming in the Skype program has created a vulnerability which could allow other rogue applications access to the SQLite database to retrieve personal information. (source:  [wired.com](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/04/skype-android-security-exploit/))

The articles I am reading states that the data was left unencrypted in the db (which I understand), but I don't understand how another application could access it.  I was under the impression that applications run in their own sandbox and cannot access other files in other directories.

Its good timing to read this article for me because I am about to begin storing some information in an SQLite database for my application, and was wondering what I need to do programmatically to secure my SQLite db  (its not sensitive data that needs to be encrypted but I want to practice good standards).

Comment: Unless there is some vulnerability I'm unaware of, I believe the device would need to be rooted to mount the /data/data partition in a way that would allow reading from another application's "sandbox".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

willytate is right in his comment, there should be no way a non-rooted device would allow an application to get into Skype's directory. **Unless** the Skype app stores its database in a shared directory. The Wired article doesn't give enough details to know for sure but any hole that would expose Skype's data (if it were in the right directory) would expose all apps.

Comment: According to the original report (http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/04/14/exclusive-vulnerability-in-skype-for-android-is-exposing-your-name-phone-number-chat-logs-and-a-lot-more/), Skype's database files are somehow marked world-readable.